# Should We Be Organized?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Blundell & Blundell Concepts in Thermal Physics tells us that in a thermally isolated system such that $\mathrm{d}Q = 0$, the inequality $\mathrm{d}S \geq 0$ always holds true. Thus, "it shows that any change for this thermally isolated system always results in the entropy either staying the same (for a reversible change) or increasing (for an irreversible change)."

From what I'm reading, if we take the universe to be a thermally isolated system, the first of the two laws of thermodynamics become:

- $U_{\text{universe}} = \text{constant}$.
- $S_{\text{universe}}$ can only increase.

Hence, any attempt of human organization can only increase the entropy of the universe, and at most give zero change (if we clean up, that can be considered as a reversible process). So by this perspective, are we only increasing the disorder of the world?

Comment: the parallel (too?) often made between entropy and disorder is merely an image. Don't take it literally. You would have to have very stringent definition of "order" for it to make sense in a few particular cases. And it wouldn't fit what you mean by disorder in a human sense.  A messy room has very little to do with the thermodynamics definition of entropy. Unless you manage to derive the entropy of your socks laying on the ground from the laws of thermodynamics ;)

Comment: Yes, [life increases the overall entropy of the universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/540561/247642) More precisely, the entropy of theliving organisms is lowered, but it happens at the expense of increasing the entropy of the environment.

Comment: "Cleaning up" will typically not be a reversible process, and entropy with increase for this too.  So, yes, the entropy of the universe is always increasing.